# access logger object from decorator with type hints python

Tags: python, logging, mypy, python-logging

I have created a `log` decorator. I have put the decorator on required functions. I also want to access the `log` object inside the decorated functions.

The code works correctly when I run the program, Later I added type hints to the code.

On running mypy I am getting error as below:

```
error: Missing named argument "logger" for "main"  [call-arg]
```

```
# logger.py

def log(*, module_name: str = "") -> Callable[[F], F]:
    """Create the logger."""    

    def decorator(func: F) -> F:
        """Initialize the logger."""

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            """Wrap the called function."""

            stream: Any = yaml.safe_load(open("log.yaml"))     

            status: bool = False      
            
            logger: logging.Logger | None = None

            # msg: str = "Unable to initialize logger"

            if stream:
                dictConfig(stream)
                logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
                # msg = "Logger Initialized.."
                status = True

            if status:
                kwargs["logger"] = logger
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)

                return value

        return cast(F, wrapper)
        
    return decorator
```

Another module

```
# common.py

@log(module_name=__name__)
def is_directory_empty(*, dir: Path, logger: logging.Logger) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    """Check whether given directory is empty or not.

    Args:
        dir(Path): directory path.

    Returns:
        tuple[bool, str]: (True, msg) if successful, (False, msg) otherwise.

    Raises: None

    """
    status: bool = False

    msg: str = "Directory is empty."

    result: tuple[bool, str]

    if any(dir.iterdir()):
        msg = "Directory is not empty"
        status = True

    logger.info(msg)  # here access log object from decorator

    result = (status, msg)

    return result
```

Main module

```
# main.py

dir: Path = some_path
status, msg = is_directory_empty(dir=dir)
```

How to resolve mypy issue or is there better way to access `log` object inside decorated functions?

Comment: I thinking to redesign the logic and use module level log instead of function level log. Any suggestions why other is preferred over function level log?

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated. Replace the decorator with a single call to `getLogger` *in* the function, and configure the the necessary loggers using the YAML file on startup.

Comment: Hi chepner, Thanks. Yes I have replace the decorator with direct call to `getLogger`.